# I want to Dual Boot Backslash Olaf with windows 10 without cd or usb

Tags: linux

The OS I am trying to download is Linux Backslash Olaf, but I currently can't use a USB or CD. Is there any way I can install it along side my pre-installed Windows 10? If there really is no way, can you tell me another OS I can do this with that is equally as beautiful

Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: Perhaps using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way you can do this is to setup [PXEBootInstall](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall). And you will need a linux system for this. If you don't have there is no way you can install your OS.

You can use it if you like in a VM(Virtual Machine) until you can use the usb and cd.

Note : Debian wiki, but it is possible to replicate in other linux distros.